# Understand Python Function

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and wanted to see if anyone could help break down and understand what this function does step by step?

```
def label(self, index, *args): 
    """ 
    Label each axes one at a time 
    args are of the form <label 1>,...,<label n> 
    APIPARAM: chxl 
    """ 
    self.data['labels'].append( 
    str('%s:|%s'%(index, '|'.join(map(str,args)) )).replace('None','') 
    ) 
    return self.parent
```

Comment: Which parts of it do you not understand?  It's a class method, so the return value `self.parent` is defined elsewhere.  Otherwise, it's doing some string manipulation and appending to a list.

Comment: @g.d.d.c For someone new to Python this is not exactly obvious, the syntax is python-specific and there are couple of functions not seen in "Hello World" examples.

Comment: @kgr thanks that's exactly right, although I usually find it best to ignore the trolls.

Comment: PS, Part of the reason this is confusing is that it's bad code. The outer `str` is completely unnecessary. Unconditionally calling `str` on each arg and then doing `replace('None','')` on the joined result, rather than just doing the right conversion in the first place, is confusing (and a red flag that someone hasn't learned list comprehensions…). Of course you do need to learn how to read code like this anyway, but it's worth knowing that this is as much the original coder's fault than your own, so you don't get too down on yourself.

Comment: @abarnert that was my thought too, looks as if someone wanted to show off and let others know how much of a hardcore programmer he or she is ignoring the readability of the code and some python guidelines along the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good idea to change the formatting, before trying to understand what it does:

```
def label(self, index, *args): 
    """ 
    Label each axes one at a time 
    args are of the form <label 1>,...,<label n> 
    APIPARAM: chxl 
    """ 
    self.data['labels'].append( 
        str( '%s:|%s' % \ 
            ( index, '|'.join( map( str,args ) ) ) 
        ).replace( 'None', '' ) 
    ) 
    return self.parent
```

So:

it appends something to `self.data[ 'labels' ]` list. We know this because `append()` is a method of [list object](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

This something is a string such that:

- string is of the form `xxx:|yyy`
- `xxx` is replaced with the value of argument `index`
- `yyy` is replaced with all the other arguments converted to strings (`map(str,args)`) and joined with `|` character (`join(...)`) so resulting in something like '`a|b|None|c`'
- every occurence of `None` in the string above is replaced with an empty string and this is appended to the list

**EDIT:**

As @abarnert pointed out it might be good to explain what does `*args` mean and why later on it's used as `args`, so here it goes.

`*args` (which is an asterisk + an arbitrary name) means "any number of anonymous arguments available further in `args` list". One can also use `**kwargs` - note two asterisk which is used for accepting keyworded arguments, i.e. ones passed to the function in the form of `foo = bar` where `foo` is the name of the argument and `bar` is its value rather than just `bar`.

As said above `args` and `kwargs` are arbitrary, one could just as well use `*potatoes` or `**potatoes` but using `args` and `kwargs` is a convention in Python (sometimes people also use `**kw` instead of `**kwargs`, but the meaning is the same - any number of anonymous and any number of keyworded arguments respectively).

Both are used if the number of arguments which the function/method should accept is not known beforehand - consider for a example a function which processes names of the party guests, one may not know how many there may be, so defining a following function makes sense:

```
def add_party_quests( *quests ):
    for guest in quests:
        do_some_processing( guest )
```

Then both calls below are valid:

```
add_party_guests( 'John' )
add_party_guests( 'Beth', 'Tim', 'Fred' )
```

This is also explained in this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/287101/680238

Comment: This is the best answer here, but it's missing an explanation of how `args` works, which might be easier to show with an example rather than trying to describe it.

Comment: @kgr so the explanation of how `args` work actually led me to solve the original problem I had, and why I was trying to figure out what this function was doing in the first place. The link to my original question is below, you should add your answer there as well and I'll accept it as the answer for that question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055783/create-dynamic-labels-for-google-chart-using-gchartwrapper

Comment: @rollingstone Didn't notice the other question :) I have added an answer which shows the proper call syntax and links to this answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the misleading lines are:

```
self.data['labels'].append( 
str('%s:|%s'%(index, '|'.join(map(str,args)) )).replace('None','') 
)
```

Those can be formatted more clearly to aid reading:

```
self.data['labels'].append( 
    str('%s:|%s' % (
        index,
        '|'.join(map(str, args))
    )).replace('None', '') 
)
```

But can be better rewritten as:

```
self.data['labels'].append(  # append to the list at `self.data['labels']`
    '%s:|%s' % (             # a string of the format X:|Y
        index,               # where X is the index
        '|'.join(            # and Y is a list joined with '|'s
            str(arg) if arg is not None else  # with each item in the list
            '' for arg in args                # being it's string representation
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: This is a nice rewrite, but I think you then need to explain how `map(str, args)` and the generator expression relate to each other.

Answer (score 1):

`*args` turns into a list of arguments called args.  `self.data['labels']` looks to be a list.  .append adds an item to the list.  The item appended is returned by the string returned by the right most part, `replace`.  To parse what string that is, start inside the parens and work your way out.  `map(str,args)` converts all the args to strings and returns that list.  `'|'.join(` takes the output of map and joins it into a single string, of the general pattern `elem1|elem2|elem3...`, it then uses the format string `'%s:|%s'`.  The first `%s` gets replaced by the value of index, the second by the string output by `'|'.join`.  It then calls replace on this string, replacing all occurences of `'None'` with `''`.  Then it returns self.parent.